# Python Excecution from WPF C# through cmd shows Error

Tags: c#, wpf, python-3.x, cmd

I have a python project that uses tensorflow libraries. I have to run this python script that takes input from a file **input.txt** and outputs the result to **output.txt** through WPF application using cmd. I tested the script individually by running it outside the WPF project by simply using cmd. It works fine and the **output.txt** is updated with the results.

I used the following code to execute the python script from WPF project:

```
string cmd = @"C:\Users\mails\Documents\example_tagging.py";
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\Users\mails\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python3.exe";
start.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", cmd);
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string results = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());   //This outputs OK
    }
}
```

The code runs fine. The cmd opens up and the starting of the python program execution reaches. But all on a sudden, python.exe shows some error, about Wrong File attributes and shuts down.(I can't read the error since it closes within a second). Which actually shouldn't happen since same input.txt works fine and creates an output.txt when run outside the WPF project on a cmd.

Why does this happen? How to solve this?

Comment: I had printed "tensorflow running" on the first line of my code in python program. When I run this code, the first message is printed in the console. So the python script is "started". But why doesn't it finish off the execution?  Which clearly works fine outside.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is, that many programs output errors on a separate stream, `StandardError`. Just because you don't see them on `StandardOutput` doesn't mean they aren't there. (No idea if this applies in your case too). One thing that could be relevant here is the working directory. Do you use a relative path for input.txt and output.txt? (if yes, set `start.WorkingDirectory` accordingly)

Answer (score -1):

```
Arguments = string.Format(" -i \"{0}\"", cmd)
```

Comment: Why would executing the script in interactive mode help?

Comment: To [Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18866436): If this answer is wrong, don't recommend deletion: downvote or comment. If the answer needs explanation, the same applies - it is still an answer.